# serde-xml-rs deseralizing u8 works but not u16

Tags: xml, rust, serde

I am trying to deserialize a xml document into a custom rust class. The attached code is the simplest form of my issue. When trying to deserialize a number value of any type other than u8 the error given is 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: invalid type: string "99", expected u16' or whatever the desired type is. serde_xml_rs seems to be casting the string value to a proper numeral value for u8  but not other types. Am I doing something wrong?

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;

extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_xml_rs;

fn main() {
    weird_example();
}



#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct SampleStruct {
    name: String,
    num_u8: u8,
    num_u16: u16,
}

fn weird_example (){
    let deser: SampleStruct = serde_xml_rs::deserialize(r##"
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <sample_struct name="Sample" num_u8="99" num_u16="99">
        </sample_struct>
    "##.as_bytes()).unwrap();
    println!("{:#?}", deser);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This crate is not very active; this is a [known bug](https://github.com/RReverser/serde-xml-rs/issues/63) which has been fixed but not published. You could use the master branch directly:

```toml
serde-xml-rs = { git = "https://github.com/RReverser/serde-xml-rs" }
```

And also replace `serde_xml_rs::deserialize` by `serde_xml_rs::from_reader`.

---

[0.3.0](https://github.com/RReverser/serde-xml-rs/pull/68#issuecomment-451960408) just come out !

So you can use the classic:

```toml
serde-xml-rs = "0.3"
```